# Excel Copy Row between sheets

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I'm using the following macro to copy row values between sheets. The cells to be copied begin from column "C" and Row "4". On column "C3" I have the header name listed. This value must not be copied to my target cell. The below code is working fine when there are values entered in "C4".  When I leave the cell "C4" empty and run my macro, the header name in C3 is being copied into my target cell . My target column and row in the below example is "F4".

Please help me out.
Macro Code :

```
Sub Process_Copy()

Dim row_start, row_end As Long
Dim col_start, col_end  As String  
Dim col_target, row_target As String
Dim ws_src, ws_target As String

col_start = "C"
col_end = "C"
row_start = 4
ws_src = "Sheet1"
ws_target = "Sheet2"
col_target = "F"
row_target = "4"
row_end = Worksheets(ws_src).Range(col_start & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ' to find last line
Worksheets(ws_src).Range(col_start & row_start & ":" & col_end & row_end).Copy
Worksheets(ws_target).Range(col_target & row_target).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
row_end = Worksheets(ws_src).Range(col_start & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ' to find last line

If row_end> = row_start Then
    Worksheets(ws_src).Range(col_start & row_start & ":" & col_end & row_end).Copy
    Worksheets(ws_target).Range(col_target & row_target).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If
```